# Split string from database, then replace it's place and calculate result

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate something based on a "method/template" in my database,
that method features variables, in form of a letter(z) + ID of another object (eg. `z1`)
It also has the needed math operators like plus and minus in it. All of it is separated by spaces.

An example would be: `z1 + z2 : 4` the normal number just being a number.
I would like to replace the 'variables z+number' with a corresponding field in my database, based on the ID, which is just the variable without the z.

And do this for every occurrence.

the SQL looks like this: `$_sql_get_zid = "SELECT bar FROM tbl_foo WHERE id='".$id_of_bar."'";`
the `$id_of_bar` being the finished variable of that.

After this, the corresponding value from the SQL statement should replace the variable (z+number) with itself and the process repeated.

I don't really know how to start on this, I have tried to create something with foreach but failed miserably, how could I take at this problem?

The result at the end of the loop should look something like this:

```
200 + 11 : 4
```

When getting the input/starting string of:

```
z1 + z2 : 4
```

---

EDIT:

For example: the database has a table `tbl_foo` with a value and id,
from another table `tbl_math`, we get the math statement with variables instead of the values we need. `Statement: z1 + z2 :4`

Now we loop over each occurrence of the letter `z` plus a number ex. `z1` and replace it with the corresponding value from the executed statement by removing the letter z from the statement and using it as a variable for the id of our "object", and getting the needed value.

Then replacing the variable `z1` in that previous string eg. the statement `z1 + z2 : 4` which leaves us with `{value from z1} + z2 : 4`

Loop until we have a final result without variables.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: 1. CLEARLY Show us an example of what is on the database. 2. Show us what you want to transform that into after you do any manipulation, 3. Show us any data you use in the manipulation. 4. Explain why you are using a loop, do you want to do this to many rows in your database. 5. Are you expecting to actually do a calculation to generate an `id` with this

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am accepting only select box input that is autogenerated for each new addition, you can only select the variables, numbers, or math operators. It won't happen here.

Comment: Ok, so what does your `id` in `tbl_foo` actually look like

Comment: @RiggsFolly loop over each occurrence of the variables eg. ``z1`` and get it's value by removing the z from it and then using the query, to get the corresponding value to it's ID and replace the variable ``z1`` with that value from the database we got earlier.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that query grabs the value "bar" from the table where the id corresponds to the variables id, z1 without the letter.

Comment: Sorry, I must be being a little stupid today. I still dont completely understand. A simple example in the question would help my confusion

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added an edit, maybe that will help you?